# Menu items disappear after a second

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a strange issue on a website I am trying to customize. 
When I activate the Avada theme, the menu items in the navigation disappear, but I can hover over them. Also the social icons in the nav are not visible and no matter what options I select in Theme Options > Menu > Menu Options, they do not apply at all.
What I have tried until now: 
Deactivated/Activated all the plugins
Deleted the demo content, reinstalled the theme. Still no result.

I took down the coming soon page. Here's a link to the website http://www.tipografiamarian.ro/ if you'd like to take a look. As you can see. while the page is loading, the navigation is visible for a second or so, then the elements in it disappear...

Has anyone else encountered this issue before? 
Please help, thank you! :)

Comment: It seems like in your *navigation*, on your `<a>` and the `<span>` within it having `height` and `line-height` something like `height: 83px; line-height: 83` and since `line-height` has value `83` instead of `83px`, it causing the disappearance of menu-items.

Comment: have you used the child-theme ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's showing `line-height:83;` (instead of 83% or 83px etc) which is causing the issue. If this is from an external javascript, you can use following snippet to override this:

```
.fusion-main-menu > ul > li > a {
    line-height: 83px !important;
  }
```

I would suggest checking/editing your javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have `line-height:83px` for the links. Just set a smaller value (you have a single row, so it can be what you want).

```
.fusion-main-menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
.fusion-main-menu > ul > li > a {
   height: 33px;
   line-height: 33px;
   margin: 20px 0;
}
```

I suggest you not adding style for menu from admin.

Comment: its not gonna help the OP as *stylesheet* `line-height:83px` is being overridden by its **inline CSS**.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay I don't think this was his problem. I'm sure he can add the important tag.

Comment: please never use OR suggest adding `!important`

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Oh, I don't use and I didn't suggest. I thought is your answer below.

Comment: What I want to say is I'm sure he can find a solution now to add the css for the links.

Comment: your code won't keep the MENU links in vertically middle, thats why, he is giving it a `line-height` value equal to the` height` of his **anchor** tag!

Comment: @Deepak Ok. He had a problem, we saw the problem, we suggest a solution and this is enough. This is not a website of writing code. Maybe he should ask something more specific, but my answer is right.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina you keep on editing your answers, after our suggestions and comments ! which means, you didn't read the question carefully, or might be somewhere you were wrong, which you don't want to accept !

Comment: @Deepak You know that the suggestion to change line-height is enough because he didn't share more details and he didn't say why he has that code inline. In first place, he should remove that style. This question is not complete and the only reason for the answers was that we wanted to help him. Personally, I thought the code I wrote was enough, but I added more info to be more clear.

Comment: @MadalinaTaina now, we are commenting more than answers ! You yourself said in my answer, that you think its inline! If not, then possibly it was coming from javascript, then obviously, your normal specificity won't help him, as it would get overwritten! and many more things ! my lady, I give up to you !! You win! I lost - let the guy decide, what worked for him

Comment: @Deepak I don't know why you answer to the question, but I want to improve my abilities to explain my code, so please don't say that ugly things. In Wordpress, style from admin appears inline. I don't know how I could be more specific. You're right, these comments are getting wired. Anyway, sorry if I said something wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89249/discussion-between-deepak-and-madalina-taina).

Answer (score 0):

when you check your code, some javascript runs, after page load
for your anchor tag, `line-height:83;` is addded, which means, *line-height is 83 times of your font-size.*

```
<a href="http://theme-fusion.com/avada/avada-xml/" aria-haspopup="true" style="overflow: hidden; line-height: 83; height: 83px;"><span class="menu-text">Home</span></a>
```

add an unit to line-height value - **83px**

```
.fusion-menu>.menu-item>a {line-height:83px;} // you can !important if you don't want to fix it via javascript/jquery
```

Comment: It is just inline style, I don't think is Javascript there.

Comment: And where is your solution via Javascript?

Comment: @MadalinaTaina - I don't know, is it from javascript or jquery, he can add simple px unit, if he is doing it that way

Comment: @MadalinaTaina I don't think, that code is added inline, if it was inline, it should have moved the link on bottom while loading itself, not later after a delay!

Answer (score 0):

Add this and you are good to go

```
jQuery('.fusion-main-menu > ul > li > a').css('line-height','83px');
```